# How do I do a SQLite to PostgreSQL migration?

Tags: ruby, sqlite, heroku

I have a problem with migrating my SQLite3 database to PostgreSQL. How and what do I need to do?

I am searching the internet, but find only migrations from MySQL to PostgreSQL.
Can anyone help me?

I need to convert my SQLite database to PostgreSQL database for Heroku cloud hosting.

Comment: your question is too vague. what **specific** problem do you have?

Comment: @mvp see upd1, i explained what i need there

Comment: Is this gem useful for your problem? https://github.com/ludicast/yaml_db

Comment: Do you need to copy database schema only or also migrate stored data?  You could simply dump schema and data into file (like `sqlite3 mydb.sqlite3 ".dump" > mydb.sql`), and use sql dump for import, some minor syntax fixes might be required.

Comment: @taro and can you write little guid how to do it? because I am newby into ruby and all which is connected wit it...

Comment: @Pigueiras maybe yes, but i don't know how to work with it=(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to try to do a binary conversion.

Instead, rely on exporting the data, then importing it, or use the query language of both and using selects and inserts.

I *HIGHLY* recommend you look at [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org). It's a great ORM, that makes switching between DBMs very easy.

Read through the opening page and you'll get the idea. Follow that by reading through the [cheat sheet](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/cheat_sheet_rdoc.html) and the rest of the documentation and you'll quickly see how easy and flexible it is to use.

Read about [migrations](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/migration_rdoc.html) in Sequel. They're akin to migrations in Rails, and make it very easy to develop a schema and maintain it across various systems.

Sequel makes it easy to open and read the SQLite3 table, and concurrently open a PostgreSQL database and write to it. For instance, this is a slightly modified version of the first two lines of the "cheat sheet":

```
SQLITE_DB = Sequel.sqlite('my_blog.db')
PGSQL_DB = Sequel.connect('postgres://user:password@localhost/my_db')
```

Base all your subsequent interactions with either database using `SQLITE_DB` and `PGSQL_DB` and you'll be on your way to porting the data.

The author of Sequel is very responsive and is a big fan of PostgreSQL, so the ORM has great integration with all its features.